# Redirecting using comment_post_redirect WordPress filter causes errors

Tags: wordpress, redirect, internal-server-error, server-error

I'm using the `comment_post_redirect` filter to redirect users to a custom page after a comment is submitted. The code works, but every now and then a user is not redirected and they get an error.
Here's my code:

```
function feedback_submitted_redirect( $location, $comment )
{
    $location = get_site_url() . '/feedback-validation?commentid=' . $comment->comment_ID;
    if_debug_logger( 'Redirecting to feedback validation', array('comment_id' => $comment->comment_ID, 'comment_author' => $comment->comment_author, 'url' => $location) );
    return $location;
}
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'feedback_submitted_redirect', 11,2 );
```

Getting any helpful feedback from users as to what exactly is happening has been almost impossible and I'm unable to replicate the issue on both the dev and live sites, which makes fixing the problem a lot harder. There are also no errors in the debug.log or the logs in the public_html folder.
After adding some debugging info to the log, I can see that the redirect function always run, but every now and then users don't arrive on the redirection page.
I believe the error they're getting is the 500 server error as one of the users said it was an 'internal server error' (although, I'd think this would be logged in the error logs). Which makes me think the redirect is probably taking too long and it's being cut out.

I can't see anything in the code though that could cause an issue. I'm just returning a new location.
Any ideas as to what could cause an issue here? I've tried searching for possible causes but none seemed to be related.

Is it possible that the second argument `($comment)` is not being set therefore causing an issue when I try to access its properties? I am going to add some checks to the function, just in case, but I can't think of any possible scenarios where the `$comment` won't be set as the filter is run after the comment is inserted into a db:

```
function feedback_submitted_redirect( $location, $comment )
{
    if( isset( $comment ) && !empty( $comment->$comment_ID ) ) {
        $location = get_site_url() . '/feedback-validation?commentid=' . $comment->comment_ID;
        if_debug_logger( 'Redirecting to feedback validation', array('comment_id' => $comment->comment_ID, 'comment_author' => $comment->comment_author, 'url' => $location) );
    }else{
        if_debug_logger( 'Redirection to feedback failed', array( 'url' => $location ) );
    }

    return $location;
}
add_filter( 'comment_post_redirect', 'feedback_submitted_redirect', 10,2 );
```

Could it be that there is some content being outputted somewhere, causing the 'Headers already sent' error? Or could the server be running out of memory?

I guess I'm just trying to find any possible causes, so I can test for them and hopefully get to the bottom of this

Comment: Unfortunately, as you've alluded to, it's so. incredibly. hard… to diagnose when users who get the error go . You shouldn't need to check the `$comment`, because it *is* set, and if it *weren't* (by some magic hullabaloo), it would just spit out some undefined errors, but shouldn't break the page (but checks are still a good practice). Maybe try submitting on a slow connection (simulate 3g in Dev Tools). From what you've posted, it looks like there might be something running on your `/feedback-validation` page that's failing (or perhaps spawning a synchronous task that's timing out/failing?)